# Is the Mangekyou Sharingan capable of controlling only the Kyuubi or all the Tailed Beasts?

Tags: naruto

This is a picture taken from *Naruto* manga chapter 385.

[image]

Is Mangekyou Sharingan capable of controlling only the Kyuubi or is it also able to control the other tailed beasts?

Also, how does Sasuke come to know the nature of the Mangekyou Sharingan?

Comment: Considering that the Nine Tails is (supposedly) the strongest of all the Tailed Beasts, it would be logical to assume that the MS is capable of controlling the other Beasts too. But not all at once.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin is there any reason why Sasuke mentions the kyuubi in particular?

Comment: Again, it could be because Kyuubi is the most powerful beast among the others. Afterall, Madara had sought after the Kyuubi and not any of the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tailed_Beast_Control#cite_note-18) says that the MS was capable of controlling all the Tailed Beasts.

> The Mangekyō Sharingan has been noted to wield the power to control over the tailed beasts, but only Madara and Obito, have achieved this feat. Sasuke at first also used his Sharingan to suppress a small amount of Kurama's chakra within Naruto's subconscious.

The MS is gained when a user of the Sharingan witness the death of someone close to them.

> It is initially awakened by the trauma suffered from witnessing the death of someone close to the user.

Sasuke got his Mangekyo Sharingan after Itachi's death.

> Sasuke Uchiha awakened his Mangekyō Sharingan after the death of his older brother

Also as a side note, Sasuke is able to use the Rinnegan to control all the Tailed Beasts at once.

> Sasuke could use his Rinnegan to put all nine tailed beasts under his control with just a glance